# Hadoop namenode format error-No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop

I am on Amazon Linux. I was trying to setup hadoop.

[ec2-user@ec2-user ~]$ hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

/home/ec2-user/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hdfs: line 276: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@ec2-user ~]$

Comment: can you post what you get out of `ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/bin/java`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: what was the cause and solution?